# String to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am implementing Spring MVC. Different String values are displayed on the jsp page.

Help me move those String values to ArrayList to reduce that bulky code.

```
 @Controller("Control")
 Public Class Controller{
 ...
 @RequestMapping()
public String init(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response,
        Model model) {
    try {
        String auth = request.getAuthType();  //All these Strings to be moved to ArrayList<String>
        String context = request.getContextPath();
        String ETags = request.getETag();
        String remoteuser = request.getRemoteUser();
        String sessionID = request.getRequestedSessionId();
        String resContent = request.getResponseContentType();
        String scheme = request.getScheme();
        String getServerName = request.getServerName();
        String getWindowID = request.getWindowID();

        PortletMode getPortletMode = request.getPortletMode();  //If these different types could also be moved <?>
        PortalContext Pcontext = request.getPortalContext();

        model.addAttribute("Name", "Sallu");
        model.addAttribute("auth",auth);
        model.addAttribute("context", context);
        model.addAttribute("ETags",ETags);
        model.addAttribute("remoteuser", remoteuser);
        model.addAttribute("sessionID",sessionID);
        model.addAttribute("resContent",resContent);
        model.addAttribute("scheme", scheme);
        model.addAttribute("getServerName",getServerName);
        model.addAttribute("getWindowID", getWindowID);
        model.addAttribute("getPortletMode",getPortletMode);
        model.addAttribute("Pcontext",Pcontext);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(ErrorUtil.convertStackTraceToString(ex));
    }
    return JSP_Page;
}
```

Also Help me change the JSP too using

```
   <%My JSP%>
   <tr>
    <td>Pcontexts------${Pcontext}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>auths------${auth}</td>
</tr>
    ...

    //To be changed to something using <c:ForEach or some Loop>
```

**Update:**

When I add this to the controller, and do as Bozho showed in the JSP, it still does not work:

```
model.addAttribute("paramsMap", request.getParameterMap());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `request.getParameterMap()` - it will give you a `Map` that you can then iterate in the JSP:.

```
<c:forEach items="${paramValues}" var="mapEntry">
    <td>${mapEntry.key}</td>
    <td>${mapEntry.value}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

`paramValues` above is an implicit variable that contains the map.

When using forward, this you need nothing else to do in the controller. You can use:   `model.addAttribute("paramsMap", request.getParameterMap())`, but it should not be necessary.

Comment: After the JSp change as you mentioned. Do I need to add just one line in controller to add that attribute. Don't I have to add all those String variables into ParameterMap. If yes, how?

Comment: @oneofthelions the map is filled by your container. You don't need to do anything